# ORACLE PL/SQL : Join cursor in subselect

Tags: sql, oracle

Is is possible to use cursor as a part of statement. Lets say i have something like this (pseudo code)

```
CURSOR SOURCE IS
        SELECT
        ID,
        FLAG
        FROM TABLE_OLD_A
        WHERE 1=1;
    
    TYPE t_new_a IS TABLE OF TABLE_NEW_A%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    var_t_new_a t_new_a;
    
    
    OPEN SOURCE;
    FETCH SOURCE BULK COLLECT INTO var_t_new_a;
    CLOSE SOURCE;
    
    so far it works.
```

Now I would like to check if the migration from old to new is ok

```
    WITH OLD_SOURCE AS
(
    SELECT 
    ID,
    FLAG
    FROM SOURCE -> can i use cursor here in order not to copy the same select from cursor ?

    )
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NEW_A
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
            FROM OLD_SOURCE
        WHERE 1=1
            AND TABLE_NEW_A.ID                      = OLD_SOURCE.ID                     
            AND TABLE_NEW_A.FLAG                    = OLD_SOURCE.FLAG                
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XML` and `TABLE` function approach as follows to use the cursor in the query as a table as follows:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2  CUR       SYS_REFCURSOR; -- DECLARING THE CURSOR
  3  L_COUNT   NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5  --OPENING THE CURSOR
  6  OPEN CUR FOR
  7  SELECT 1 AS A, 5 AS B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 3 AS A, 12 AS B FROM DUAL;
  9
 10  -- USING THE CURSOR AS A TABLE
 11  SELECT MAX(B - A)
 12    INTO L_COUNT
 13    -- FOLLOWING CODE CONVERTS THE CURSOR TO TABLE
 14    FROM (
 15  SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(SRC),'ROW/A') A,
 16         EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(SRC),'ROW/B') B
 17    FROM TABLE ( XMLSEQUENCE(
 18  XMLTYPE(CUR).EXTRACT('ROWSET/ROW')
 19  ) ) SRC
 20  ) CUR_TABLE;
 21
 22  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result: ' || L_COUNT);
 23  END;
 24  /
Result: 9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```